# Apache Ignite ScanQuery realted IgnitePredicate Filter not getting invoked from Service

Tags: ignite, predicate

I have deployed a Ignitechache relate service my "componentCache"-named cache and implemented a scan-query related function for the same.
   The function uses a `ScanQuery` instance to which a custom `IgniteBiPredicate` implementation is passed to filter the data. 
    However the Query always returns an empty data-set even when the cache is having the data satisfying the filter criteria .

```
<code>
    ScanQuery< UUID,Component> scan= new ScanQuery< UUID,Component>(new 
     IgniteBIPredicate< UUID,Component>()
      {
       @Override
        public boolean apply(UUID uuid,Component c){
         return c.getName().equals("ComponentOne");
        }
    });
     List< Entry< UUID,Component>> qqlist=componentCache.query(scan).getAll(); 
 </code>//HERE <b>qqlist is always null </b><br>
```

Why would the data returned be always null ? Am i missing something;
   Is there any specfic configuration to be added to use IgniteBiPredicate based scan queries? I am using spring-bean-configuration xmls as inputs for starting ignite nodes.

Note: it returns values when this scan-query with predicate is executed from stand-alone data-node, but doesn't return anything when its run from a service-node.

Comment: Note it works fine from a stand-alone client node. but not when the scan-query is getting executed from within an IgniteService running on a service node

Comment: Are you sure that you execute ScanQuery on service-node after as data was populated to cache but not before?

Comment: How do i validate this? The ignite-cluster has Cassandra persistent store. When the service-node startsup, isn't it expected to load data from persistent storage and start servicing the requests?

Comment: No, data from store won't be loaded automatically. You need invoke IgniteCache#loadAll method yourself. You can do it in org.apache.ignite.services.Service#init method.

Comment: The IgniteCache#loadAll method needs me to pass all the Ids/keys for which I need the data. Since this would be on init of the Ignite cluster , i won't have the keys that i need to load at this point of time, hence i cannot use this pattern.

Comment: In this case you can use IgniteCache#loadCache method. The method will load all data from underlying store.